# Jquery mobile, How to use changePage to update changeHash and Parameters

Tags: jquery-mobile

```
options.dataUrl = urlObj.href;
$.mobile.changePage( $page, options );
```

dataUrl contains the complete url with parameters

```
http://example.com/#sales?p=page
```

but the above code only updates the url with hash only, after the new page loads... the url changes to

```
http://example.com/#sales
```

and does not apply ?p=page.

Here is the complete function, check the last few lines....

```
function getSPList( urlObj, options ){
var pageName = urlObj.hash.replace( /.*p=/, "" ),
pageSelector = urlObj.hash.replace( /\?.*$/, "" );

$.ajax({
    url:"getSPList.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {p: pageName},
    success:function(result){
        if ( result ) {
            var $page = $( pageSelector ),
                $header = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=header)" ),
                $content = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=content)" ),
                markup = "<ul data-role='listview' data-filter='true' data-filter-placeholder='Search Salesperson...'>";

            for ( var i = 0; i < result.sp.length; i++ ) {
                markup += "<li><a href='#addClient?p="+ result.sp[i].id +"' data-transition='slide'>" + result.sp[i].name + "</a></li>";
            }
            markup += "</ul>";

            $content.html( markup );
            $page.page();

            $content.find( ":jqmData(role=listview)" ).listview();

            options.dataUrl = urlObj.href;
            options.changeHash = true;

            $.mobile.changePage( $page, options );
        }           
    }
});

return
}
```

Comment: you mean passing parameters between pages? if `dataUrl` contains `#sales?p=page` it will show it all, not only `#sales`.

Comment: Nope, just want the address bar to show the complete url with parameters after the new page is loaded.

Comment: It should work normally `$.mobile.changePage(page, { changeHash: true, dataUrl: urlObj.href });` your example above using `options` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced the same problem and here is what I've found as of version 1.3.2:

Inside `$.mobile.changePage(toPage, options)` `options.dataUrl` is passed through `path.convertUrlToDataUrl()` before being stored and used.

Inside `path.convertUrlToDataUrl()` everything before and including the '#' as well as everything after and including the '?' is stripped.

Further down inside of `$.mobile.changePage()` before the url is passed to `$.mobile.navigate()` I see this:

```
// rebuilding the hash here since we loose it earlier on
// TODO preserve the originally passed in path
if( !path.isPath( url ) && url.indexOf( "#" ) < 0 ) {
    url = "#" + url;
}
```

So it seems to be a bug in jQm.  For my app I'm adding this inside the bottom of the previously mentioned if statement:

```
var query_index = (settings.dataUrl || '').indexOf('?');
if (query_index > -1) {
    url += settings.dataUrl.substring(query_index);
}
```

This solves the initial problem but I'm unsure about potential negative side effects or if there is a better workaround out there.

Comment: Hi Josh, thank you for the comment. I am done with that project, I will update or mark your answer right once I get a chance to work on it. Thank you.